# Passing data by reference to build it

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

Under C++ I usually ran into an error.
Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class ClassData
{
public:
    ClassData() { a=-1; }

public:
    int a;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { m_classData = 0; }
    MyClass(ClassData* classData) { m_classData = new ClassData(*classData); m_classData->a=1; }

    inline bool getClassData(ClassData* classData) {
        if (m_classData) { classData = m_classData; return true; }
        else return false;
    }

private:
    ClassData* m_classData;
};
```

Now in the main I run this test code:

```
ClassData cdata;
MyClass* m_myClass = new MyClass(&cdata);

int value = 0;
ClassData classData;
if (m_myClass->getClassData(&classData))
    value = classData.a;
```

If the code is run, `value` is equal to -1 (instead of 1).

First question: why I've not been able to take a reference to `ClassData` in `MyClass`? While I'm thinking to have the `ClassData` object of `m_myClass` (like doing `m_myClass->m_classData` if it would be public), in reality I'm calling the member `a` on local `ClassData` object.

I was thinking that the cause was that I cannot change the local variable address, but if I change the code into this:

```
ClassData* classData=0;
if (m_myClass->getClassData(classData))
    value = classData->a;
```

I get my program crashing.

Second question: what is the correct way to manage this situation? Is the issue located in the program main function or in how `getClassData` is defined giving room for mistakes?

Comment: You pass pointer by value, you don't pass anything by reference.

Comment: There is no single reference taking operation in provided code, the question is really unclear.

Comment: So if I've understood correctly I should change into this: `if (m_classData && classData) { *classData = ClassData(*m_classData); return true; }` right?

Comment: I'm not sure that `m_classData && classData` is certain to do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
bool getClassData(ClassData* classData) {
  if (m_classData) { classData = m_classData; return true; }
  else return false;
}
```

Notice that `classData` is a *local* variable. It dies when the function terminates, so the function really does nothing except report whether its `m_classData` is null or not.

So in the first case:

```
ClassData classData; // <-- classData.a is -1
if (m_myClass->getClassData(&classData))
  value = classData.a; // <-- classData.a is still -1
```

In the second case:

```
ClassData* classData=0;      // classData is null
if (m_myClass->getClassData(classData))
    value = classData->a;    // classData is still null
```

you dereference a null pointer, which is **Undefined Behavior**. You're lucky all it does is crash.

A correct (but still unsafe) way to do it is like this:

```
bool getClassData(ClassData* classData) {
  if (m_classData!=0 && classData!=0)
    { classData->a = m_classData->a; return true; }
  else return false;
}
```

I say "still unsafe" because this function cannot really verify that these pointers point to valid data structures. To avoid this danger you must refrain from using pointers so much, and look into references.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but... any way to get that pointer from the main program? Something similar to myClass.m_classData->a (if m_classData would be public)

Comment: @ABCplus: I don't understand your question. Which pointer do you want `main` to pass to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Using values instead of pointers simplifies things and will also remove your memory leak. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d182f728d4413d0)

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassData
{
public:
    ClassData() { a=-1; }

public:
    int a;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {  }
    explicit
    MyClass(ClassData const& classData) { 
        m_classData = classData; 
        m_classData.a=1; 
    }

    ClassData const& getClassData() const {
        return m_classData;
    }

private:
    ClassData m_classData;
};

int main()
{
    ClassData classData;
    MyClass myClass( classData );

    classData = myClass.getClassData();
    int value = classData.a; 

    std::cout << value;
}
```

Comment: I cannot change class member ClassData from being a pointer. I would like to know how to get a pointer to that object from the main function ( myClass.m_classData)